# Tensorboard: The requested URL could not be retrieved

Tags: tensorboard

I have tensorboard summaries saved in `D:\0`. I launch tensorboard from `cmd`, change the drive from `C` to `D` and launch `tensorboard --logdir="D:\0"`. The problem is, tensorboard sometimes works, sometimes I get the error:

```
ERROR
The requested URL could not be retrieved
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL: http://nsv:6006/

Unable to determine IP address from host name nsv

The DNS server returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.
This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is webmaster.
```

One time to fix it, I change the `computer name` restarted the laptop and it worked. But I don't want to do this everytime. Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. This is really silly. The reason for this error seems to be because I am connected to VPN to access lab servers. Once I disconnect from the VPN, tensorboard works.